# How to automatically fetch new name server on VPN connect

Tags: ubuntu, dns, vpn

I am running ubuntu xenial 16.04

We are using openvpn to connect to a virtual private cloud. That cloud has it's own DNS server (as does our local route - home or office).

When I connect to the VPN all of the IPs in that network are available but I can't reach any by host name. The reason is simple: the resolv.conf file still shows my local office nameserver. If I manually overwrite the resolv.conf to have the correct name server all is good.

So, how can I get it to automatically reconfigure resolv.conf upon connecting to the VPN?

Can I hook in to a system event and execute a script?

Comment: Normally there's an option to allow the VPN to push its own DNS server. Which client are you using— tunnelblick?

Comment: I am using the official openvpn client. Somewhere I read that the VPN process can't update DNS.

Comment: Have you tried the `--register-dns` option? Alternatively there are client-side options you can set, as dhcp-options (the flip side of the instructions here https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#dhcp)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The OpenVPN package has a script for this in `/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf`. You need to configure it with:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

This will fetch the DNS server addresses from the `dhcp-option DNS` options passed by the OpenVPN peer/server and configure `resolvconf` accordingly. It handles `dhcp-option DOMAIN` as well.

It is not perfect however, because this will prepend those name servers to the list of existing name servers instead of overwriting the list of name servers. If you are using `openresolv` the `-x` can be used to overwrite the DNS configuration instead of preprending to it.

---

If you're using `systemd-resolved`, you can use the `/etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved` which hooks into `systemd-revolved` instead of `resolvconf`.

```
script-security 2 
up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down-pre
```

On Debian, this script is in the `openvpn-systemd-resolved`.

Comment: above these 2 lines, you will also need to add `script-security 2` or run your `openvpn` with `--script-security 2`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with: There is a switch that allows you to run a script when the tunnel is up and running. I use the switch to essentially overwrite the resolv.conf file with one I know is correct. It's a total hack, I know.

```
sudo openvpn --up reset-dns.sh --client client.ovpn
```

the script (reset-dns):

```
#!/bin/bash
cp ~/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Also, for those say "OMG! You're running that tunnel as root!" It won't run any other way; even before my DNS hack.

I am definitely open to a better way. The network manager for ubuntu simply won't work. I have cut tickets to ubuntu on this repeatedly